# autocompletion will not work when importing a class from another module within a different project

Tags: python, class, inheritance, autocomplete, project

I want to use some functions I have developped from another project.
I'd like to have autocompletion working to suggest developped methods.

I hav efound many examples on the net/stackoverflow that are wrorking properly but classes that inherit are all locally based.

I do have a base project where all functions have been developed in a class. I want to use those methods from another project as such

******* Working Example ********

```py
class Aclass:  
    def __init__(self):  
        pass  
    def foo(self):  
        print("hello")  

class Bclass(Aclass):  
    def __init__(self):  
       super().__init__()  

classexp = Bclass()  
classexp.foo() # => when typing ".", foo(method) does appear as a choice
```

******* Non Working Example ********

```py
import sys  
sys.path.append('C:\\**\\**\\**\\Folder')  
from File import Aclass  

class Test_class(Aclass):  
    def __init__(self):  
        super().__init__()  

MyObject = Test_class()  
MyObject. # => when typing ".", foo(method) does NOT appear
```

---

I am working with PyCharm Community 2021.3 with Python 3.6.8

Can you help?

Comment: if you indent your code, it would certainly help a lot

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to add the second project in project structure : File => Settings => Python Interpreter => Project Structure

When doing that , it allows to retrieve autocompletion